# Date-time field to seconds SharePoint 2013 Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, date-time

I am trying to convert the "Created" column field, or at least create a computed field, in SharePoint 2013 Online to display MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS. Is this possible in the UI or is it a limitation of Sharepoint?

I have tried a computed value in a text field using : `=TEXT(Created, "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS")` but all I get is an error when I click OK. I figured it was because created was a value set after you save a form. I also tried "NOW" but that didn't write out to seconds, only to minutes.

Comment: What error do you get when you are using Created?

Comment: "Sorry something went wrong"
"The formula contains reference(s) to field(s)."

Comment: I created a column using this formula - =TEXT(Created, "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS") and it didn't give me any error

Comment: @Tom , localization do you use? For some reason the separator is not the same depending on locale. So try separating the Created and date format with a semi colon(;) instead of a comma (,)

Comment: @AndresAune, I tried the semi colon and got a different error "The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported."

Comment: @Keerthi, that is odd, are you entering it in the Calculated Value Field?

Comment: @Tom: Yes I did

Comment: @Keerthi: That's I am entering too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, the issue was I was not using a computed field when I first created it